# Why does ora_rowscn change without updating a table

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I work with `ora_rowscn` to track the changed rows on a table and to work with updated rows.

Last week I noticed that for some (not all) of my tables that I created with `rowdependencies`, the `ora_rowscn` changes without any transactions on the table. I mean if I select `max(ora_rowscn)` I get always higher number.

Here is an example how I created my table

1. creating table

   ```
   create table test ( test_id number, txt varchar2(5) ) rowdependencies;
   ```
2. Inserted some data into the table

   ```
   insert into test values(1,'a');
   insert into test values(2,'b');
   insert into test values(3,'c');
   ```
3. Queried the table more than once with ORA_ROWSCN

   ```
   select max(ora_rowscn),max(b.current_scn) from test a, v$database b
   ```

Every time I queried I got a higher `max(ora_rowscn)`.

On MetaLink i found two reported Bugs (Bug 14093863, Bug 9814923) that seems to be the same problem, but  set as not a Bug.

Why does it happen and what is the solution to get it work or fix it?

Comment: I don't see that; max(b.current_scn) is increasing of course, but max(ora_rowscn) stays stable. But then you said it wasn't every table, which is also interesting. Which patch level are you running? Do you actually see this behaviour with your test table?

Comment: we are using 11.2.0.3 and 11.2.0.4, but i'm not sure if it also was on a 11.2.0.4. machine.
I can not give you any further information, what you can do in order to readjust it to. I do not know what is the cause that the table starts to behave like this. I don't have an DB EE at home, its an example at my work.

Comment: On your work machine, does the `test` table that you used here demonstrate the problem?  Or if you built the `test` table exactly as you've done here, would it be one of the tables that don't demonstrate the problem?  Are you certain that you don't have some process that is touching rows in the tables that have their `ora_rowscn` values increasing?  Even if those processes aren't actually changing data, perhaps they're running an `UPDATE` that sets the values in a row to their current values?

Comment: @JustinCave not the test table, i have staging table  where i import data from files once a day (with more columns) with  primary key and some simple index, but  i dont blive that it could be a problem. `test `  table is just an example to make it simple.  yes i'm sure that there no processes that makes updates, inserts and other `DMLs` on this table. in my post i posted some metalink bugs with the same problem, so the problem exists. I think it must be a more complex memory(PGA/SGA?) problem, what makes Oracle confuse.

Comment: Is your staging table (which I assume is where you see this) an external table? Or populated by SQL\*Loader, or some other process?

Comment: @AlexPoole no, is a normal db table like a `test` table in example, with just more columns and some index, no partitining, no compression, simple "magic" table. it will be populating from external table by using merge statement. i also tried to use flashback with records which `ora_rowscn` was changed, i got no information, i couldn't also convert the `ora_rowscn` to `timestamp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we asked our Oracle contact and got the following answer.

"It is not a bug, its undocumented feature."

> The ORA_ROWSCN is generated when the blocks are cleaning out the
>   transactions. There are two kinds of block clean out may occur:  fast
>   clean out and delayed clean out.
>
> Note that for delayed clean out, the exact commit-scn of a transaction
>   may not be available when a block modified by that transaction is
>   cleaned out and therefore we may get upper-bounds for the commit-scn.
>   So, for those blocks with  fast clean out we can update the ORA_ROWSCN
>   right after the commit of a transaction;
>
> However, for those blocks with delayed clean out we only update the
>   corresponding ORA_ROWSCN the next time  we touch the block(DML or
>   select). It can be several hours later. It is possible that we are
>   doing bunch of staff in other  tables (thus the SCNs get incremented)
>   and we are not doing any transaction in this table T. However when we 
>   queried the ORA_ROWSCN for table T we can still get a recent figure
>   for SCN, since the block has just been  cleaned out (but the
>   transaction has been committed several hours ago).  This ORA_ROWSCN is
>   the upper bound of the commit time for the last transaction.

How it looks the problem does exist. If I have understood correctly, there no simple solution for this case.

I hope it would help to understand other user the problem.

Here i found some more unsefull information about block cleanout

- [Clean it up](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2009/06/16/clean-it-up/)  by Jonathan Lewis
- [Delayed Block cleanout](http://hemantoracledba.blogspot.de/2008/10/delayed-block-cleanout.html)

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
select 
  max(a.test_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY a.ora_rowscn desc),
  max(a.txt) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY a.ora_rowscn desc),
  max(a.rowid) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY a.ora_rowscn desc),
  max(a.ora_rowscn)
from test a;
```

This should identify the row which is changing.

Comment: sorry, but what i should do with your query? my question was, why ora_rowscn increments without any changes

Comment: this should return rowid of the row, having the max ora_rowscn. So you clould see whether particular row is changing it's scn or whether all rows are affected. also you can translate rowid into file number and block id to use alter database dump block. Or you can see logminer to see the query which touches the particular rowid.

Comment: so this really is not an answer (but the query was too long for comment), it could help you with further investigation

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help me to solve my problem. :)

Comment: @hotfix there were some random SGA corruptions, which led to courious behaviours. But "consitent" changes of database blocks, should be quarded by redo-log writes. So by using logminner you can prove/disprove whether something is happening in the database in backgound. Also dump of batabase block could show whether the order of rows within the block is changing(for example). Also the view v$bh might give you some information. When you know filenumber, and block id you can dump datafile block manually by using `dd` on Unix so you can see whether this is changing on disk or only in buffer cache.

Comment: I think there are more ways how scn can be stored internally in the database. So maybe Oracle just wrongly interprets scn. For example scn can "jump" forward whenever you do query via dblink. Oracle instances synchronize their SCNs via distributed transactions.