# Oracle Query to track the changes for table with context particular day

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query which gives me the times whenever last DML operation happen in the table , i wan to modify it a bit to track for the whole day so that i can get the coplete history whatever changes have happened with context to the particular table for the day , so please let me know how to modify this below query

```
SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(MAX(ORA_ROWSCN)) from mytablename;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a companion to `scn_to_timestamp` which gives you the SCN for a given time; so to see rows whose `ora_rowscn` is today you could do:

```
select * from table_a where ora_rowscn >= timestamp_to_scn(trunc(sysdate));
```

There are a few caveats though, of the top of my head. First, [by default `ora_rowscn` is the same for all rows in a block](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ORA_ROWSCN-Pseudocolumn.html), even if the rows were modified at different times. If the table was created with [`rowdependencies`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6__CJAEEGDA) then it will only show the rows actually modified.

Second, the SCN to timestamp translation is only available during the redo/flashback window, though you should be OK for 120 hours, so if you're looking on the same day or soon afterwards you shoudl be OK. [See this for a bit more info.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22681705/266304)

And third, you need to be a bit careful about when and how you query the data. If a change is made just before midnight but isn't committed until after midnight, and you run your query exactly at midnight to see the last changes for the day, then you won't see the uncommitted change. And if you query again later then you won't see it because it's now a change yesterday.

Also [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30901574/266304).