# Oracle ora_rowscn to get delta

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, etl, talend

`ora_rowscn` as definition from oracle,

> You cannot use this pseudocolumn in a query to a view

so can I use the ora_rowscn column to get the delta and updated data from the oracle table in my ETL job?

Comment: if you want to use it, you should change your tables to ROWDEPENDENCIES. If your table is created without ROWDEPENDENCIES, the number is updated for a block and not for individual data records
Note, however, that it may cause problems in Oracle. I had a question about it some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512372/why-does-ora-rowscn-change-without-updating-a-table

Comment: as I comprehend I can not relay on rowscn on update or get the delta as it's not  just increment on updated row but it's can increase with clean out process for row and block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately even if you use ROWDEPENDENCIES you can hardly rely on SCN - for replication purposes. There are situations where SCN can change or is generated at COMMIT time.

**ORA_ROWSCN Pseudocolumn**

> For each row, ORA_ROWSCN returns the conservative upper bound system
>   change number (SCN) of the most recent change to the row. This
>   pseudocolumn is useful for determining approximately when a row was
>   last updated. It is not absolutely precise, because Oracle tracks SCNs
>   by transaction committed for the block in which the row resides.

Search for "delayed block clean out"